# What does enable detailed cloud watch metrics do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am unable to figure out the difference what does enable detailed cloud watch metrics does in aws - api gateway - logs/traces

[image: d watch metrics does in]

Answer (score 3):

Detailed CloudWatch metrics for API Gateway will include individual metric data to breakdown each resource/method combination too.

With this enabled you can visualise performance for specific requests such as a `/search` request latency, or alarm if you return `5XX` errors for your `/book` request.

By default CloudWatch metrics are limited to API and stage.

Enabling this has no effect on logs/traces.

Comment: how does the  /search request latency mean ? And where to find it ?

Comment: Hey, so the `/search` was an example, if you check out CloudWatch from the console and select metrics on the left hand side you can find API Gateway metrics. In addition to the standard ones you will also have metrics based on method/resource as well :)